# Windows, cURL 60 unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: windows, curl, composer-php, php-7

I have already tried a lots of options available for this problem on stackoverflow, unfortunately nothing is working for me so far.

It started with composer installation. My env details are listed below:

1. OS: Windows 7
2. PHP V 7.1.10, XAMPP version
3. I am running MINGW64, (which was installed with git v2.1.5)

   > curl --version
   >
   > curl 7.56.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.56.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.26.0
   >
   > Release-Date: 2017-10-23
   >
   > Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
   >
   > Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy MultiSSL Metalink

Now here it seems `CURL` with `OpenSSL` is installed correctly.
When I was doing `composer require or install` it was reported me an error as follows:
[image]

I searched and figured out that its the local certificate problem so I downloaded the certificate/bundle from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html, placed the certificate under `C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\` and changed the PHP.ini

> curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
>   openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\curl-ca-bundle.crt"

this never worked. Then I placed my certificates under `C:\Windows\System32\curl-ca-bundle.crt`, changed the ini still it didn't work.

Then I downloaded `cacert.pem` from

> https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download

and repeated steps to make it work with `pem` file.
However I am afraid still no success here.
Can anyone help me whats wrong going on here? Any help in this direction is much 
appreciated.

Comment: Guys while dealing with this issue, please ensure you know the right proxies and have it configured in system. In My case installation and `crt` files and other settings were correct. But proxy was screwed. So please also take a look at that.

Answer (score 7):

### This is for **`Windows`** users, using `curl-7.57.0-win64-mingw` or similar version.

I have already shared this on another thread, but I think Windows users might stumble upon this question and my answer might help. So, sharing the step-by-step process.

This error basically means, curl is failing to verify the certificate of the target URI. If you trust the issuer of the certificate (CA), you can add that to the list of trusted certificates (e.g. It's a local `IIS` certificate, and you trust it for your development purposes).

For that, browse the URI (e.g. on Chrome) and follow the steps

1. Right click on the `HTTPS` secure padlock  icon on address bar
2. Click on `certificate`, it'll open a window with the certificate details
3. Go to 'Certification Path' tab
4. Click the ROOT certificate
5. Click `View Certificate`, it'll open another certificate window
6. Go to `Details` tab
7. Click `Copy to File...` button, it'll open the export wizard
8. Click `Next`
9. Select 'Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)'
10. Click `Next`
11. Give a friendly name that you can remember e.g. 'MyDomainX.cer' (browse to desired directory) and save
12. Click `Next`
13. Click `Finish`, it'll save the certificate file

#### So what did we do?

We basically ***saved the root certificate*** for the desired site (that we actually trust) as a local file. What do we do next?

#### Add that certificate to the list of trusted certificates

14. Now open this `.cer` file and copy the contents (including `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`)
15. Now go to the directory where `curl.exe` is saved e.g. `C:\SomeFolder\curl-7.57.0-win64-mingw\bin`
16. Open the `curl-ca-bundle.crt` file with a text editor (right click and open with...)
17. **Append** the copied certificate text to the end of the file. Save

#### What did we do now?

We added the certificate (content) to `curl`'s main certificate bundle. So now `curl` will recognize this certificate and allow the domain.

Now your command should execute fine on `curl`.

Answer (score 5):

Just posting this here for posterity as I spent the last 2 hours on this.
NOTE: only tested on windows.

1. Make sure you have the curl version with ssl included ( the latest exe installer has it)
2. Download the cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
3. Rename cacert.pem to curl-ca-bundle.crt
4. Move the cacert.pem file to the curl.exe directory.

Fixed.

Comment: It seems to be useless now, as the recent windows zip packages already contain this file.